# How to prevent gpkg size increase when I delete attributes?

Tags: qgis, geopackage, delete, file-size

I have a file, `polygons.gpkg` that I am using in QGIS.  Its original file size is 48MB.

When I do nothing except delete a handful of the attribute table's fields, I expect the file size to decrease.  However, it instead increases to 85MB.

After deleting the fields, if I export as a new gpkg (Export > Save Features As), the new file is only 38MB.  This result makes sense to me.

**Is there a way to "clean up" whatever extra data is getting stored in the original `polygons.gpkg` so that its size on disk is reduced?**  That would be a more convenient solution than exporting anew...

Answer (score 21, accepted):

** EDIT: You can now do this in the QGIS file browser by right clicking on the .gpkg and selecting vacuum **

You should VACUUM your database to reduce the size of the database after deleting rows/ dropping tables.

You can use the DB Manager core plugin. Open DB Manager and select your GeoPackage connection from the tree on the left. Select the *spanner* icon and input the SQL command.

[image: DB Manager SQL window]

Alternatively you can use *ogrinfo* from the command line:

```
ogrinfo your_db_file.gpkg -sql "VACUUM"
```

or *sqlite*

```
sqlite3 your_db_file.gpkg 'VACUUM;'
```

The latter solutions are useful to create a cron job (Linux) or scheduled task (Windows) to VACUUM your database automatic.

Comment: I've noticed that you can now do this in the QGIS file browser by right clicking on the .gpkg and selecting vacuum.